# Filter countries in correct order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have a list of countries that I am filtering through to get the best matching result first based on the input term. I use 2 examples to show the issue. Search for the term `unit` or `in` you'll see that the expected returned country names order is not correct. The expected results are to return those country names that start with the `term` and after that priority, return countries with partial `term` string matches. Here is the code with both `terms`, the current results, and the expected results in the first 2 comments below:

```js
const {observable, action, computed} = mobx;
const {observer} = mobxReact;

@observer
class Country extends React.Component {
    /*
     1. Type term: 'unit'
        Results:
        - Emirates, The United Arab
        - United States
        - The United Kingdom
        SHOULD BE:
        - United States (this should be first since it starts with the term 'unit')
        - The United Kingdom (this should be second since term 'unit' occurs in the name before "Emirates, The United Arab")
        - Emirates, The United Arab

     2. Type term: 'in'
        Results:
        - China
        - India
        - The United Kingdom
        SHOULD BE:
        - India (this should be first since it starts with the term 'in')
        - China (this should be second since 'in' term occurs in the name before "The United Kingdom")
        - The United Kingdom
    */

    @observable filterTermValue = '';
    @observable countriesList = [
      {'slug': 'amsterdam', 'name': 'Amsterdam'},
      {'slug': 'china', 'name': 'China'},
      {'slug': 'uae', 'name': 'Emirates, The United Arab'},
      {'slug': 'iceland', 'name': 'Iceland'},
      {'slug': 'india', 'name': 'India'},
      {'slug': 'usa', 'name': 'United States'},
      {'slug': 'uk', 'name': 'The United Kingdom'},
      {'slug': 'vienna', 'name': 'Vienna'}
    ];

    @computed get filtered() {
      let filteredList = this.countriesList.filter(
        t=>t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue)>-1
      );

      return filteredList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              Term: <input placeholder="Start typing country"
                 onKeyUp={this.onChangeFilterTerm} />

              {this.filtered.map(country =>
                  <div key={country.slug}>
                    <p>{country.name}</p>
                  </div>
              )}
          </div>
        )
    }


    @action onChangeFilterTerm = (e) => {
        this.filterTermValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Country />,
  document.body
);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tbdn74s/2/)

Any idea how to update the `filtered()` function to return the expected results correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to sort the returned array in the `filtered` method. Taking a look at the use cases you mention in your question, I think you could sort the array by the index where the match starts.

So, your `filtered` method could look like:

```
@computed get filtered() {
    return this.countriesList
        .filter(t => t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue) >-1)
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue) - b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@computed get filtered() {
  let filteredList = this.countriesList.filter(
    t=>t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue)>-1
  ).sort(
    (a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue) - b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue)
  );
```